# Jquery Button OnClick Run System Command

Tags: php, jquery, button, click

Can anyone provide a simple example of running a system command in the background when a button is clicked.

eg: when this is clicked:

```
<button onclick="startprocess">Start</button>
```

run

`$var = system('tail -f /mail.log > /download/mail.log 2>&1 & echo $!');`

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing the example would involve an ajax call and running the command with PHP. You should probably try to figure it out yourself, it's not that hard, and then ask again when and if you fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

html :

```
<button id="run_system">Start</button>
```

js :

```
$('#run_system').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'run.php'
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

run.php :

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec('tail -f /mail.log > /download/mail.log 2>&1 & echo $!');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

unprivileged javascript in a browser cannot run or execute programs for security reason. You must have shell access for this.

give us more details of your environment.
Also you can have a look on this. This may help.
http://www.sitepoint.com/take-command-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can Try with this. in index.php, make an ajax call to command page. it will execute it and will return the response.

index.php

```
<script>
   function startprocess()
   {
       jQuery.ajax({ 
                type:'post',
                url:'command.php',
                data:[],
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(rs)
                {}
                failure : function(rs)
                {}
        });
    }
    </script>

<button onclick="startprocess();">Start</button>

command.php

system('tail -f /mail.log > /download/mail.log 2>&1 & echo $!');
```